# How to evaluate an impulse/response model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, impulse-response

This is my first experience in signal processing, so don't treat me badly :)
However, I have estimated an impulse-response model using the MATLAB System Identification toolbox. The output, validated on unseen data, has a good fit, approximately around 80%. However, when I export the object `imp` - its type is `idtf` - containing the estimated model, I don't know how to evaluate it on unseen data. Obviously, in the structure is contained the polynomial structure of the model, but it bothers me to write a function to estimate it... Is there any quicker procedure?

Comment: Have you tried methods idtf?  struct(obj) actually lets you see what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of evaluating the model response to arbitrary data is the lsim command. As you don't provide more information with respect to your data and/or model an example below (taken straight from the `MATLAB` help). See `help lsim` or `doc lsim` for more information.

```
% create model
%
num = [1 4];
den = [1 20 5];
G = idtf(num,den);

% evaluate response
% 
t = 0:0.01:5;   
u = sin(t);   
y = lsim(G,u,t);

% plot
%
figure;
plot(t,y)
```

In addition, if desired, you can evaluate the model impulse, step and/or frequency response using the `impulse`, `step` and `bode` commands.